# Можно ли так загружать несколько изображений на сервер в PHP?

Tags: php

В форме два поля:

```
<input type="file" name="userfile">
<input type="file" name="userfile2">
```

И обработчик формы:

```
 if($_FILES['userfile']['type'] != "image/gif" && 
    $_FILES['userfile']['type'] != "image/png" && 
    $_FILES['userfile']['type'] != "image/bmp" && 
    $_FILES['userfile']['type'] != "image/jpeg") 
    {
         include("blocks/redimg.php");
    }

    else
    {
         if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 307200) {include("blocks/yellowimg.php");}
         else
         {
             $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
         $ext = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['userfile']['name']));
         $new_name = time().'.'.$ext;
         $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$new_name;

         if($_FILES['userfile']['error'] == 0)
         {
             if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
             {

             }
         } 
         }   
    }
//****************************************************************
     if($_FILES['userfile2']['type'] != "image/gif" && 
    $_FILES['userfile2']['type'] != "image/png" && 
    $_FILES['userfile2']['type'] != "image/bmp" && 
    $_FILES['userfile2']['type'] != "image/jpeg") 
    {
         include("blocks/redimg.php");
    }

    else
    {
         if ($_FILES['userfile2']['size'] > 307200) {include("blocks/yellowimg.php");}
         else
         {
             $uploaddir2 = 'uploads/';
         $ext2 = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['userfile2']['name']));
         $new_name2 = time().'.'.$ext2;
         $uploadfile2 = $uploaddir2.$new_name2;

         if($_FILES['userfile2']['error'] == 0)
         {
             if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile2']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile2))
             {

             }
         } 
         }   
    }
```

Почему-то загружается только одно изображение, которое выбрано во втором поле, а в базу записывается переменная первого поля. Можно ли так загружать несколько изображений? Или так не делается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень плохая конструкция:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile2']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile2))  
             {}
```

гораздо лучше просто

```
@move_uploaded_file(from, to);
```

при проверке на то, является ли файл изображением, вы не проверили еще несколько типов, чтобы сократить код лучше всего подойдет стандартная функция [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getimagesize.php), но безусловно только с "@".

изрядно повозившись, я предлагаю сокращенную версию кода, которая выполняет поставленную задачу:

```
    <?
if(count($_POST)>0){// проверка на то, отправлена ли форма
foreach($_FILES as $k=>$f) {// поскольку изображений несколько, делаем цикл по всем файлам массива $_FILES, где $k будет отвечать за имя поля, $f можно спокойно игнорировать, она нам не нужна
  if (!$_FILES[$k]['error']) {// проверка на ошибки, более короткий синоним $_FILES[$k]['error']==0
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$k]['tmp_name'])) {//существуют люди, которые хотят взломать ваш сайт, выбрав что-то очень плохое в поле формы. этой функцией мы проверяем, загрузился ли файл проще говоря
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$k]['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$_FILES[$k]['name'])) {// перемещаем в папку uploads
        echo 'Файл: '.$_FILES[$k]['name'].' загружен.<br />';
      }
    }
  }
}
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file1">
<input type="file" name="file2">
<input type="submit" name="ok">
</form>
```

Кстати о переименовании, функцией time() вы вряд ли получите уникальное имя. лучше так:

```
    $dir='/uploads/';
    $now=time();
    while(file_exists($filename = $dir.$now.'-'.$_FILES[имя_поля]['name'])) $now++;
```

Comment: Если честно, мало что понял в этом коде

Comment: Я добавил много поясняшек, если все равно не понятно - спрашивайте

Comment: Да, теперь стало понятно. Спасибо.

Comment: Можно не игнорировать `$f`, а везде, где Вы пишите `$_FILES[$k]` заменить на более короткое и очевидное `$f`

Comment: Точно, не подумал как-то :)

Comment: > гораздо лучше просто
> @move_uploaded_file(from, to);

@Виктор Павлов, забудьте этот совет! Была б возможность, то за такие заявления, я бы десяток минусов влепил. И вообще, старайтесь не прибегать к использованию подавления ошибок и уж тем более при отладке. Правильный подход  - смотрите ответ, который дал @Равнодушный, пункт первый.

Answer (score 4):

Как вижу такой код в вопросе - сразу хочется написать ответ на хинди...

Нет, так файлы загружать нельзя:

1. Сначала нужно проверить `0 == $_FILES[]["error"]`, а потом уже все остальное.
2. `$_FILES[]["type"]` - бесполезная переменная, она выставляется браузером и то не всегда. Истинный тип файла все равно узнать не получится, а еще его может и не быть.
3. Что мешает отправлять файлы массивом и обрабатывать в цикле? К чему это копирование кода?
4. 99% за то, что оба вызова функции `time()` в этом коде возвращают одинаковый результат, поэтому второй файл просто затирает первый. Генерируйте более сложные имена и проверяйте файл на существование перед перемещением.
5. и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Так файлы нельзя загружать, или не рекоммендуется? А как тогда проверить тип файла? (нужны только изображения).

Comment: Это работает только потому, что это `php`. Тип изображения определяют обычно теми средствами, которыми с изображениями в итоге работают. В случае `GD` - `getimagesize()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
if(count($_POST)>0){// проверка на то, отправлена ли форма
foreach($_FILES as $k=>$f) {// поскольку изображений несколько, делаем цикл по всем файлам массива $_FILES, где $k будет отвечать за имя поля, $f можно спокойно игнорировать, она нам не нужна
  if (!$_FILES[$k]['error']) {// проверка на ошибки, более короткий синоним $_FILES[$k]['error']==0
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$k]['tmp_name'])) {//существуют люди, которые хотят взломать ваш сайт, выбрав что-то очень плохое в поле формы. этой функцией мы проверяем, загрузился ли файл проще говоря
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$k]['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$_FILES[$k]['name'])) {// перемещаем в папку uploads
        echo 'Файл: '.$_FILES[$k]['name'].' загружен.<br />';
      }
    }
  }
}
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file1">
<input type="file" name="file2">
<input type="submit" name="ok">
</form>
```

в этом скрипте
хотел быстренько добавить запись названий фаилов в таблицу mysql, но они стали записываться в столбец, а не в строчку.